# Converting unsigned char byte to int C

Tags: c, char, int, unsigned

I have an unsigned char to represent a 1-byte hexadecimal integer value say like the following. I want to get its integer value.

```
unsigned char thing = 'F'; // its integer value = 15
printf("Char: %c, Unsigned Char: %X, Int: %d\n", (char)thing, thing, (int)thing);
```

From the print statement I get the following:

```
Char: F, Unsigned Char: 46, Int: 70
```

However none of these are `15` like i'm expecting/wanting. How can I convert this unsigned char to an `int i` where `0 <= i <= 15`?

Comment: `'F'`'s code (integer value) is not 15... Why are you expecting 15?

Comment: sorry maybe i was not clear... i'm using the unsigned char to represent the hexadecimal representation. so `0=0, 1=1,..., A=10, B=11,...,F=15`

Comment: But `thing = '1'` is not the same as `thing = 1`. Same for `'F'` and `F`.

Comment: I found my answer in the duplicate question answers: `int num = strtol (&thing ,NULL,16);` works

Comment: `strtol` 1st argument requests CString. It must be done with a null-terminator(`'\0'`). So Change it to `int num = strtol((char[]){ thing, '\0'}, NULL, 16);`